# Can not create a StreamReader class from a string

Tags: c#, streamreader

I cannot create a StreamReader object from a string. Here is the code:

```
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
```

Here is the exact error I am getting:

> The best overloaded match for 'StreamReader'(StreamReader(Stream)) has some invalid arguments

It just is not making any sense, I looked at file IO on the microsoft website and everywhere else (including on this site) and it is just not finding the string constructor for StreamReader. I am using VS 2013 professional as my IDE, and I am also using the monogame(XAML) template.

Comment: Assuming you are referencing System.IO; and that filePath is indeed a string? Can you include more code?

Answer (score 4):

[There *is* a `StreamReader(string)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx), but *not* in all profiles - note how the overload is [missing the icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamReader(v=vs.110).aspx) for the PCL and Windows Store Applications. So either;

1. The constructor overload is limited by (does not exist in) the target profile, or
2. There is a different StreamReader in scope.

Given the error message is indicating it is trying to best-match `StreamReader(Stream)`, the probable cause is #1, as said Stream-consuming constructor *is* available in a Windows Store Application.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. Apparently you can create a stream using `TitleContainer.OpenStream(String)`.

Here is the line of code.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(TitleContainer.OpenStream(filePath));
```

Comment: Of course. That calls the [supported in your profile] `StreamReader(Stream)` constructor.